# Are there any difference between commas at the end of a line or not of a CSV File?

Tags: excel, file, csv, format, formatting

**csvFile1.csv**

> abc,def

**csvFile2.csv**

> abc,def,

Are there any difference between them?

Comment: The latter may confuse some csv reading routines into reading an additional empty element. The former is therefore probably more common and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no issue with this except that it may create an empty field at the end, besides that there is no other difference I believe.

EDIT: It also depends where you will be using your CSV file. I do know some places where these  CSV files must have a specific format but as I said this depends on the use of the file itself.